# Adding a Plug or Interface to Existing Snap

Tags: snap

I read through [this](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management), and it seems for a given snap (e.g. xournalpp), you can check it's snap connections, existing interfaces, etc with `snap connections [snap_name]` but is there no way of adding a standard interface (e.g. removable-media) to an installed snap? (xournalpp, for instance did not have the removable-media interface listed, but had the home interface listed.)

I've seen others talk about it being impossible to add custom interfaces to installed snaps, but can one not even add such a common interface as removable-media to an existing snap? Is this really required to be set up by the developer alone?

I also saw some talk about yaml files controlling the availability of these interfaces, but didn't manage to find where such a file would exist, or if this is a source file not available in a compiled/installed snap?

It seems like the inability to access removable drives by any snap in general unless the dev has specially statically written this into a yaml file somewhere is a bit crazy, but maybe I am missing something here?

edit: I am asking in general about adding interfaces to existing installed snaps, not specifically about removable-media, as others have found various workarounds for accessing removable-media via various hacks (mounting the media somewhere else, installing with the --classic flag, etc.). The first is hacky, and the second option pretty much eliminates the entire purpose of snaps (for me at least). I am looking for a straightforward way to do this for any existing interface from the core snap (at least).

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, it's up to the publisher (and in some circumstances, Canonical, for some restricted connections) not the user.

However, let's play. On my laptop I'm starting this with zero snaps installed.

```bash
snap list
No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.
```

Let's download the snap you specified.

```bash
snap download xournalpp
Fetching snap "xournalpp"
2022/10/29 18:25:28.566806 store_download.go:143: no host system xdelta3 available to use deltas
Fetching assertions for "xournalpp"
Install the snap with:
   snap ack xournalpp_69.assert
   snap install xournalpp_69.snap
```

Now we will unpack it:

```bash
unsquashfs xournalpp_69.snap 
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 8 processors
8406 inodes (9923 blocks) to write

[==================================================================================================================================================================================================|] 9923/9923 100%

created 7946 files
created 973 directories
created 460 symlinks
created 0 devices
created 0 fifos
created 0 sockets
```

Now edit `./squashfs-root/meta/snap.yaml` in your favourite text editor.

In the apps -> xournalapp -> plugs section, we can add (for example) "`- joystick`" to add that interface, as it isn't already specified.

Now we repack it:

```bash
snap pack squashfs-root
built: xournalpp_1.1.1_amd64.snap
```

Now we install it (dangerous flag needed because we are installing a random (modified) snap, not one we grabbed from the store)

```bash
snap install ./xournalpp_1.1.1_amd64.snap --dangerous
xournalpp 1.1.1 installed
```

Let's see if that worked:

```bash
snap connections xournalpp 
Interface                 Plug                       Slot                             Notes
alsa                      xournalpp:alsa             -                                -
content[gnome-3-38-2004]  xournalpp:gnome-3-38-2004  gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004  -
content[gtk-3-themes]     xournalpp:gtk-3-themes     gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes   -
content[icon-themes]      xournalpp:icon-themes      gtk-common-themes:icon-themes    -
content[sound-themes]     xournalpp:sound-themes     gtk-common-themes:sound-themes   -
dbus                      -                          xournalpp:dbus-xournalpp         -
desktop                   xournalpp:desktop          :desktop                         -
desktop-legacy            xournalpp:desktop-legacy   :desktop-legacy                  -
gsettings                 xournalpp:gsettings        :gsettings                       -
home                      xournalpp:home             :home                            -
joystick                  xournalpp:joystick         -                                -
network                   xournalpp:network          :network                         -
opengl                    xournalpp:opengl           :opengl                          -
pulseaudio                xournalpp:pulseaudio       -                                -
removable-media           xournalpp:removable-media  -                                -
wayland                   xournalpp:wayland          :wayland                         -
x11                       xournalpp:x11              :x11                             -
```

Great success. So, yes, you can. This means the app is installed via "sideloading" so it's not going to get automatic updates - but then if it did, you'd lose joystick connectivity. :D

Comment: Thanks for adding info on how to edit the yaml files; hopefully that will assist someone.  Although it doesn't look too complicated, I would still consider this a workaround rather than something straightforward like an install flag, and something I definitely would not like to remember doing with each update. Any other tools I used that have isolation in mind (docker, singularity, VMs, etc.) seem to have such flags/options, so it still bewilders me how people can manage snaps without going bonkers.